# android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1 - Could not get unknown property 'processResourcesTask'

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Android Studio 3.0.1

In project build.gradle:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
```

In my app/build.gradle I have:

```
kapt {
    arguments {
        arg("resourcePackageName", android.defaultConfig.applicationId)
        arg("androidManifestFile", variant.outputs[0]?.processResourcesTask?.manifestFile)
    }
}
```

And project success build and run.
But after I update android gradle plugin:

```
 classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
```

I now get build error:

```
Error:(304, 0) Could not get unknown property 'processResourcesTask' for ApkVariantOutputImpl_Decorated{apkData=Main{type=MAIN, fullName=prod_no_verification, filters=[]}} of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.ApkVariantOutputImpl.
<a href="openFile:myproject\app\build.gradle">Open File</a>
```

Comment: try to change it to `variant.outputs[0]?.processResources?.manifestFile`

Comment: Yes, it's help me. Thanks

Comment: I converted it to an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property `processResourcesTask` is not available in Gradle 3 or higher.

Alternatively you can change the line

```
arg("androidManifestFile", variant.outputs[0]?.processResourcesTask?.manifestFile)
```

to

```
arg("androidManifestFile", variant.outputs[0]?.processResources?.manifestFile)
```